# I can be awakening

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is unique 
>   My infix is forceful 
>   My suffix is frankly conclusive 
>   Yet, as a whole, I can be awakening

What am I?

HINT:

> My prefix is an abbreviation you can find in a definition

Comment: By any chance is your infix rot13(nez)?

Comment: @Dooper I probably shouldn't reveal this half an hour after posting...but rot13(anl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a shot at this

> espresso - this coffee is awakening

My prefix is unique

> **esp.** - abbreviation for especially, as first and foremost is close to unique

My infix is forceful

> **press** - to press is to force

My suffix is frankly conclusive

> **so** - bring a discussion to an end saying so

Comment: Well done, this is correct! Sounds like that hint made it too easy, haha.

Comment: @mestackoverflow -ah maybe, I thought of various types of this answer on first seeing this puzzle, but didn't connect it til I saw the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Could it maybe be

> **Eyes**?

---

*My prefix is unique*

> The mathematical number e is unique

*My infix is forceful*

> This was the one I wasn’t 100% on, but the [Y Force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_Force) was part of the Chinese Army in WWII

*My suffix is frankly conclusive*

> ’Yes’ is a rather frank conclusion

*Yet, as a whole, I can be awakening*

> Eyes will open when you awaken from sleep

I’m not 100% sure if this is right, and I feel this answer might be a bit too short of a word but is this the answer you’re looking for?

Comment: Nice answer, but not quite. I'm starting to think the first line is too vague though..

Comment: @mestackoverflow hmmm probably more so than the other lines at least. I’ve been trying I- E- One- Un- Me-  as the prefix but can’t get the rest to work. It’s a really nice short riddle, but might need the addition of an extra line or a hint if it goes too long without a correct answer, I’d keep it as it is for now! Who knows, someone might get it still :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Have you looked into rot13(vq, rtb) for line 1?

Also, does the title have anything to do with rot13(Gur Njnxravat ol Xngr Pubcva?). The grammar mistake seems intentional.

Comment: @VirtualValentin no, it doesn't have anything to do with that.